# Unresolved Reference to any class from kotlinx.coroutines. package

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

In an android Studio Project I received where kotlin coroutines library is added as dependency

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.8",
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.8",
```

Although everything builds and runs perfectly well, in Android Studio itself I see Unresolved Reference Errors on every import of a class from kotlinx.coroutines package.
And in my External Libs folder the jar file for corouties core seems not to have appropriate files: see screenshotsenter image description here[image: Here is the error]

[image: And here is my are the jars]

I searched the internet and tried various things that I could find but there is very few information on this topic and I nothing helped me

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

I seem to have found the culprit.  It appears to be the `kotlin.mpp.enableGranularSourceSetsMetadata=true` in the gradle.properties file.  When I commented it out the libraries imported properly and the classes work as expected.

I filed an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195805181) on issuetracker.google.com:

END EDIT

I'm having the same issue using org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.1-native-mt.

It's not clear where I would post a bug report...

Creating a new project and adding just adding coroutines has not reproduced the issue.  So I have seen it work.  My best guess at the moment is that it's some sort of conflicting dependency or dependency that causes a problem with AS pulling in the external library jar and sources.

Here is the project external libraries where it is not working. Image showing external klibs for commonMain, nativeMain:

[image: Image showing external klibs for commonMain, nativeMain]

And here is the one that works properly. Image showing coroutines-core with source and metadata:

[image: Image showing coroutines-core with source and metadata]